# How to add django-mptt rebuild to migration?

Tags: django-migrations, django-mptt

I have add the django-mptt to existing database, and create the new migration.

Migration process was asked for default values for `level`, `left`, `right` and such fields, but doesn't add the `model.rebuild` operation to migration file.

How to add rebuild operation to migration file manually?

Answer (score 9):

Try the following:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import migrations
from mptt import register, managers


def rebuild_tree(apps, schema_editor):
    YourMPTTModel = apps.get_model('your_app', 'YourMPTTModel')

    manager = managers.TreeManager()
    manager.model = YourMPTTModel

    register(YourMPTTModel)

    manager.contribute_to_class(YourMPTTModel, 'objects')
    manager.rebuild()


class Migration(migrations.Migration):


  operations = [
      migrations.RunPython(
          rebuild_tree
      )
  ]
```